# How to recover inbox and outbox mails in Eudora

Tags: email, data-recovery, pop3, email-client

I use Eudora 6.2 for single POP3 mail. Sudden power failure in my machine left all inbox, outbox and other mailboxes empty. As Eudora was set up not to leave mails in server, I can't get mails from the POP3 server.

Eudora was set up in a local drive (not in default location).
As attachment was set up to store in different folder, all attachment still exist BUT all mails are gone.

How can I recover the lost mails from Eudora?

Answer (score 0):

You can recover the mail by copying the installation dir and data dir.

Eudora was normally installed into the C:\Program Files\Qualcomm\Eudora directory, you should paste the Entire Qualcomm folder (including the Eudora folder within) into the C:\Program Files directory on the new system, then reinstall the Eudora program into the new location to ensure that system DLL files are properly updated.

And Copy the entire Eudora Data directory (where your eudora.ini file is located)

If you do not know where your Eudora data directory is and are currently running Eudora 6.2 or newer, you can find out by going to the Help, About Eudora menu.

Comment: i'll try it out....

Comment: @atSad 10 years later, did this ever work for you?